# How to sum rows with the same keys?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

In my code, `df` is defined like this

```
df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet, sep='\s*,\s*')
```

I have a `[86 rows x 1 columns]` dataframe `df` which looks like this on `print(df)`

```
          0
Male    511
Female  461
Male    273
Female  217
Male    394
Female  337
Female  337
Male    337
...
```

I wish to write a code that would `merge` the `Male` and `Female` entries like this

```
          0   1   2   3 ...
Male    511 273 394 337 ...
Female  461 217 337 337 ...
```

The final task I need to do is to `.sum()` the male row and then the female row to get the total of each sex. I am new to python and pandas and I haven't been able to make much progress so far. Any help, tutorial, documentation would be great! Thank you!

Edit: By `keys` I mean the indexes. I hope these labels of Male and Females can be used to 'club' these rows together, but I don't know how to.

Edit: I have accomplished my last task directly via

```
print(df.ix['Female'].sum())
print(df.ix['Male'].sum())
```

But I am yet to achieve my forst task. Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: `ix` has been depreciated, use `loc` or `iloc` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @jpp

Comment: @Vibhu - So performance is important?

Comment: @Vibhu - I ask because curious why is for you jpp solution better :)

Comment: Hi @jezrael, for my task, yes it is important since I will have to deal with large datasets. Also, for some reason, `df = df[0].unstack()` did not work for me. I will run it again and post the error message for you today. I'm sorry I forgot to share it yesterday. Thank you so much!

Comment: So in your datasets are only `male` and `female` ? If error is keyerror, `df = df.iloc[:, 0].unstack()` should working nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` + `transpose`:

```
cats = ['Male', 'Female']

res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(group.values) for _, group in df.groupby(level=0)],
                axis=1, ignore_index=True)\
        .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(cats)))\
        .transpose()

print(res)

          0    1    2    3
Male    511  273  394  337
Female  461  217  337  337
```

**Performance benchmarking**

`concat` + `transpose` appears to perform ~4x better than `cumcount` + `unstack`. This is not generally the case, but it is true where we have a small number of large groups, such as here.

```
def jpp(df):
    cats = ['Male', 'Female']
    res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(group.values) for _, group in df.groupby(level=0)],
                    axis=1, ignore_index=True)\
            .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(cats)))\
            .transpose()
    return res

def jez(df):    
    df.index = [df.index, df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()]
    df = df[0].unstack()
    return df

df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit jpp(df2.copy())  # 12 ms
%timeit jez(df2.copy())  # 52.7ms
```

Answer (score 5):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new columns names created by reshaping by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df.index = [df.index, df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()]

print (df)
            0
Male   0  511
Female 0  461
Male   1  273
Female 1  217
Male   2  394
Female 2  337
       3  337
Male   3  337
```

---

```
df = df[0].unstack()
print (df)
          0    1    2    3
Female  461  217  337  337
Male    511  273  394  337
```

And then `sum` all rows by `axis=1`:

```
print (df.sum(axis=1))

Female    1352
Male      1515
dtype: int64
```